# Browse an excel by columns PHPEXCEL

Tags: php, html, codeigniter-3, phpexcel

I need to read an excel file and upload the information to my DB, the structure of the information is the next one.

[image]

The idea is to take A1, then B2 to B8, N amoung of times, i make the test with a txt file and almost works, but I can't make it work in PhpExcel file.

```
    while(! feof($file)) {
 $i=0;
    $data = array();
    while($i<8){
        $line = fgets($file);
        echo $line. "<br>";
        array_push($data, $line);
        //echo $data[$i];
        $i=$i+1;
    }
    $medida_data=array(            
        'id_solicitud'  => 133,
        'programa'  => 1,
        'orden' => $data[0],  
        'ges' => $data[1],                   
        'dimension' =>$data[2],                   
        'actividades' => $data[3],
        'ejecucion' =>$data[4],
        'fecha_comprometida' => date('Y-m-d',strtotime($data[5])),
        'fecha_creacion' => date('Y-m-d'),
        'plazo' => $data[6],                   
        'estado' => 1
    );     
    $this->propuestas_model->register_medida_plan($medida_data);
    echo "<br>";
    $i=0;
```

At the moment I have a simple formula to run the Excel file, that's goes from row to row, but I don't know how to jump between columns.

```
    $reader->open($inputFileName);
    $count = 1;
    $worksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
    //Numero de Hojas en el Archivo 
        foreach ($worksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
            if($row[0] != ''){
             if($count > 1) {
                    $data = array(
                        'fecha_edicion' => date("Y-m-d", strtotime($row[0])),
                        'orden' => $row[1][1],
                        'ges' => $row[2],
                        'dimension' => $row[3],
                        'ejecucion' => $row[4],
                        'actividades' => $row[5],
                        'medios_verificacion' => $row[6]
                       
                    );  
                    //$this->db->insert('medidas',$data);                       
                }  
                $count++;                           
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get your point right, you can add 2 counter in your code

$row_ounter for counting rows

$group_counter for counting each 8 rows

For example, rows counter start with 1 for first Folio, so next Folio number should be 9, and next 17, and next 25, and...

And when you convert this idea to code:

```
$row_ounter = 0;
$group_counter = 0;

foreach ($worksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
    
    $row_ounter++;
    
    if ($group_counter == 0) {
        //It's Folio
        $group_counter++;
    
    } elseif ($row_ounter % ($group_counter * 8) == 1) {
        //It's Folio
        $group_counter++;
    
    } else {
        //It's NOT Folio
    }
}
```

also notice that:

> PHPExcel - DEAD
>
> The project has not be maintained for years and must not be used
> anymore. All users must migrate to its direct successor
> PhpSpreadsheet, or another alternative.